# How to uncompress gzipped data in a byte array?

Tags: python

I have a byte array containing data that is compressed by gzip.
Now I need to uncompress this data. How can this be achieved?

Comment: You are (a) running (b) reading the docs of which version(s) of Python?

Comment: Hello, we're using Python 2.2.1.

Comment: Hello, if you are using Python 2.2.1 then you don't have a `bytearray`. You must have a `str` object, or maybe an `array.array('b')`. To confirm, `print type(the_thing)` and edit your question to show the result.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

zlib.decompress(data, 15 + 32) should autodetect whether you have `gzip` data or `zlib` data.

zlib.decompress(data, 15 + 16) should work if `gzip` and barf if `zlib`.

Here it is with Python 2.7.1, creating a little gz file, reading it back, and decompressing it:

```
>>> import gzip, zlib
>>> f = gzip.open('foo.gz', 'wb')
>>> f.write(b"hello world")
11
>>> f.close()
>>> c = open('foo.gz', 'rb').read()
>>> c
'\x1f\x8b\x08\x08\x14\xf4\xdcM\x02\xfffoo\x00\xcbH\xcd\xc9\xc9W(\xcf/\xcaI\x01\x00\x85\x11J\r\x0b\x00\x00\x00'
>>> ba = bytearray(c)
>>> ba
bytearray(b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x08\x14\xf4\xdcM\x02\xfffoo\x00\xcbH\xcd\xc9\xc9W(\xcf/\xcaI\x01\x00\x85\x11J\r\x0b\x00\x00\x00')
>>> zlib.decompress(ba, 15+32)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must be string or read-only buffer, not bytearray
>>> zlib.decompress(bytes(ba), 15+32)
'hello world'
>>>
```

Python 3.x usage would be very similar.

**Update** based on comment that you are running Python 2.2.1.

Sigh. That's not even the last release of Python 2.2. Anyway, continuing with the `foo.gz` file created as above:

```
Python 2.2.3 (#42, May 30 2003, 18:12:08) [MSC 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> strobj = open('foo.gz', 'rb').read()
>>> strobj
'\x1f\x8b\x08\x08\x14\xf4\xdcM\x02\xfffoo\x00\xcbH\xcd\xc9\xc9W(\xcf/\xcaI\x01\x00\x85\x11J\r\x0b\x00\x00\x00'
>>> import zlib
>>> zlib.decompress(strobj, 15+32)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
zlib.error: Error -2 while preparing to decompress data
>>> zlib.decompress(strobj, 15+16)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
zlib.error: Error -2 while preparing to decompress data

# OK, we can't use the back door method. Plan B: use the 
# documented approach i.e. gzip.GzipFile with a file-like object.

>>> import gzip, cStringIO
>>> fileobj = cStringIO.StringIO(strobj)
>>> gzf = gzip.GzipFile('dummy-name', 'rb', 9, fileobj)
>>> gzf.read()
'hello world'

# Success. Now let's assume you have an array.array object-- which requires
# premeditation; they aren't created accidentally!
# The following code assumes subtype 'B' but should work for any subtype.

>>> import array, sys
>>> aaB = array.array('B')
>>> aaB.fromfile(open('foo.gz', 'rb'), sys.maxint)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
EOFError: not enough items in file
#### Don't panic, just read the fine manual
>>> aaB
array('B', [31, 139, 8, 8, 20, 244, 220, 77, 2, 255, 102, 111, 111, 0, 203, 72, 205, 201, 201, 87, 40, 207, 47, 202, 73, 1, 0, 133, 17, 74, 13, 11, 0, 0, 0])
>>> strobj2 = aaB.tostring()
>>> strobj2 == strobj
1 #### means True 
# You can make a str object and use that as above.

# ... or you can plug it directly into StringIO:
>>> gzip.GzipFile('dummy-name', 'rb', 9, cStringIO.StringIO(aaB)).read()
'hello world'
```

Answer (score 6):

Apparently you can do [this](http://codingrecipes.com/ungzip-a-string-in-python-gzinflate-in-python)

```
import zlib
# ...
ungziped_str = zlib.decompressobj().decompress('x\x9c' + gziped_str)
```

Or this:

```
zlib.decompress( data ) # equivalent to gzdecompress()
```

For more info, look here: [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html#module-zlib)

Comment: From what I've read these operate on strings, but the data i need to decompress is a byte array. Or can zlib.decompress be used on byte arrays?

Comment: You can try converting the byte array to a string. Something like `reduce(lambda x, y: return str(x) + str(y), bytearray` could do - but i'm not a python programmer, so i wouldn't know

Comment: oh, i think it's `bytes(bytearray)`. Try that?

Comment: -1 @evgeny and 4 gadarene upvoters: Neither of your zlib-related suggestions work. `gzip` != `zlib`. A gzip stream INCLUDES a zlib stream. To decompress a gzip stream, either use the gzip module, or use the zlib module with arcane arguments derived from much googling or reading the C-library docs at zlib.net.

Comment: gzip module only supports stream - sometimes the data doesn't come as a stream - and it seems wrong to push it into being stream just to decode it.

Comment: Uncaught exception: <class 'AttributeError'>: module 'zlib' has no attribute 'decrompress'