# Compress data in Java and decompress in Python

Tags: java, python, python-2.7

So I am trying to compress (gzip or similar format) a JSON object before I throw it in my MySQL database.  I am currently storing the data as BLOB.  I have tried to use the following Java method to compress the data:

```
public static byte[] compress(String str) throws Exception {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream obj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(obj);
    gzip.write(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    gzip.close();
    return obj.toByteArray();
}
```

and then store it in the database using `setBytes()` with a `PreparedStatement` and am having no issues with this.  What I am having issues with is decrypting the data in Python 2.7  I have tried using `zlib.decompress()` to no avail.  It can't seem to read the data that Java is storing.  I also need to write a conversion script in Python to compress the old rows into this new format.  So whatever format I needs to be readable by the Python `decompress()` whether it was compressed with Java or Python 2.7

I am happy to provide anymore information that can assist in helping to find a solution to my dilemma.

Thanks.

EDIT: Some of the Python Code:

```
class KitPvPMatch(Base):
    """ The SQLAlchemy declarative model class for a User object. """
    __tablename__ = 'kit_pvp_matches'
    __table_args__ = {
        'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB',
        'mysql_charset': 'utf8'
    }

    match_id = Column(INTEGER(11), autoincrement=True, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    season = Column(Unicode(5), nullable=False)
    winner = Column(Unicode(16), nullable=False)
    loser = Column(Unicode(16), nullable=False)
    ladder_id = Column(TINYINT(4), nullable=False)
    data = Column(BLOB, nullable=False)

# The line in question
jsonData = json.loads(zlib.decompress(match.data))

# The error
error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

Comment: The gzip module seems to only be for files? I am using a database.

Comment: Ahh, right you are.  Sorry.  I clearly didn't read your post very carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a post that goes over [unzipping using zlib with a stream.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571913/python-unzipping-stream-of-bytes)

Otherwise, have you tried the gzip docs for gzip.py. You may need a temp file. The documentation for [gzip is here.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html)  There is a fairly decent solution for this approach in the following post on [decompression.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123223/howto-uncompress-gzipped-data-in-a-byte-array).

If you haven't already, ensure that you are getting bytes back from SQL. Python is flexible so it may be a string. Call bytearray(string) on your string if this is the case.

If that doesn't work:

1. What format is the data in when returned by your SQL command?
2. What error, if any are you getting?

Comment: The gzip module seems to only be for files? I am using a database.

Comment: you could try pumping to a temp file and then unzipping. I added some beef but without your python code (where the problem seems to be), I am a bit at a loss,

Comment: try this post on unzipping gzipped data as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571913/python-unzipping-stream-of-bytes

Comment: i would have dropped this in the comment field fyi, but I don't have the rep yet.

Comment: I added some of the Python code to help give some more information as to whats going on.

Comment: ill get on it but it might be a few hours. im at work

Comment: ever get a chance to look over this again?

Comment: sorry, I've been busy its finals week and I work 40-60 hours as well. I can get back to it Tuesday after my last final. The other links I posted should get you pretty close to a solution.

Comment: so sorry about not getting up code. I'm finishing a major project for work. ill edit when I can.

Answer (score 1):

I'm rehashing the answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12572031/7298096 because the question of this thread is exactly the topic I was looking for. In my case the Java code is compressing the content with `DeflaterOutputStream` and then encoding with `Base64.encodeBase64String`
The
`error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check` is resolved if I provide a
32 signal offset to zlip decompres:

```
import base64
import zlib

data = "ENCODED_COMPRESSED_STRING_FROM_JAVA"

output_str = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(data), 32 + zlib.MAX_WBITS).decode('utf-8')
```