# Decoding urllib.request response

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I'm getting this response when I open this url:

```
r = Request(r'http://airdates.tv/')
h = urlopen(r).readline()
print(h)
```

Response:

```
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xed\xbdkv\xdbH\x96.\xfa\xbbj\x14Q\xaeuJ\xce\xee4E\x82\xa4(9m\xe7\xd2\xd3VZ\xaf2e\xab2k\xf5\xc2\n'
```

What encoding is this?
Is there a way to decode it based on the standard library?
Thank you in advance for any insight on this matter!

PS: It seems to be gzip.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's gzip compressed HTML, as you suspected.

Rather than use `urllib` use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/) which will decompress the response for you:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://airdates.tv/')
print(r.text)
```

You can install it with `pip install requests`, and never look back.

---

If you really must restrict yourself to the standard library, then decompress it with the `gzip` module:

```
import gzip
import urllib2
from cStringIO import StringIO

f = urllib2.urlopen('http://airdates.tv/')

# how to determine the content encoding
content_encoding = f.headers.get('Content-Encoding')
#print(content_encoding)

# how to decompress gzip data with Python 3
if content_encoding == 'gzip':
    response = gzip.decompress(f.read())

# decompress with Python 2
if content_encoding == 'gzip':   
    gz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO(f.read())
    response = gz.read()
```

Comment: I see, requests does handle it without breaking a sweat. I would still prefer to get it done with a standard library. I think this answer may lead me to such a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123223/howto-uncompress-gzipped-data-in-a-byte-array

Comment: got it: `zlib.decompress(gz_data, 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)`

Comment: oh I posted the solution I am using, but your answer is more complete! Retrieving the content-encoding from the page is very useful! Thank you.

Comment: @zvone: yes, in Python 3, but not Python 2. OP is probably using Python 3 so this is a good point and I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I am using Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

mhawke's solution (using `requests` instead of `urllib`) works perfectly and in most cases should be preferred.
That said, I was looking for a solution that does not require installing 3rd party libraries (hence my choice of `urllib` over `requests`).

I found a solution using standard libraries:

```
import zlib
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

r = Request(r'http://airdates.tv/')
h = urlopen(r).read()
decomp_gzip = zlib.decompress(h, 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)
print(decomp_gzip)
```

Which yields the following response:

```
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n (continues...)'
```

Comment: Imagine the server enables and disables compression and you have no knowledge if it. Will this work for a non-compressed stream or will this throw an error? The beauty of the "requests" approach is, it handles it automatically, as I understand. just curious